# How to clone objects in Scala?

Tags: scala, clone

Recently had some problems to copy a complex object. Its internal organization is composed of several nested objects. I noticed that the `clone()` is not available.

What is the best solution to solve the problem?

Comment: Which object?  It makes a huge difference what it is.  Maybe there's an easy way, maybe there's a hard way, and maybe there's no way at all (and that may be for a good reason!).

Comment: Often the best solution is to design you program in such a way as to avoid cloning completely. Scala's good support for immutable data structures makes that particularly easy.

Comment: Note that if your object is a case class, there's a copy method generated by the compiler, which allows full copies as well as overriding just certain fields via named parameters.

Comment: I got the solution in this entry: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032227/implementing-clone-in-scala][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032227/implementing-clone-in-scala

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If that complex object is mutable or contain mutable parts, then the solution is the same as in Java. Check Java questions & posts about it and do that.

If everything is immutable, then you don't need and shouldn't clone anything. At best, you should make a shallow copy of the object, changing only the fields that need changing, and, at worst, you use something like lenses or zippers to copy some deep object and propagate the change upwards. See questions on Scala about lenses and zippers for that.

Answer (score 2):

I got a sample code that works for cloning mutable-state objects here: [Implementing '.clone' in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032227/implementing-clone-in-scala)