# Implementing '.clone' in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to figure out how to `.clone` my own objects, in Scala.

This is for a simulation so mutable state is a must, and from that arises the whole need for cloning. I'll clone a whole state structure before moving the simulation time ahead.

This is my current try:

```
abstract trait Cloneable[A] {
  // Seems we cannot declare the prototype of a copy constructor
  //protected def this(o: A)    // to be defined by the class itself

  def myClone= new A(this)
}

class S(var x: String) extends Cloneable[S] {
  def this(o:S)= this(o.x)    // for 'Cloneable'
  def toString= x
}

object TestX {
  val s1= new S("say, aaa")
  println( s1.myClone )
}
```

a. Why does the above not compile. Gives:

```
error: class type required but A found
  def myClone= new A(this)
                   ^
```

b. Is there a way to declare the copy constructor (`def this(o:A)`) in the trait, so that classes using the trait would be shown to need to provide one.

c. Is there any benefit from saying `abstract trait`?

Finally, is there a way better, standard solution for all this?

I've looked into Java cloning. Does not seem to be for this. Also Scala `copy` is not - it's only for case classes and they shouldn't have mutable state.

Thanks for help and *any* opinions.

Comment: If you clone state _every time step_ then why is "mutable state a must"?  Mutability is efficient only when you _don't_ need to make a clone every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Traits can't define constructors (and I don't think `abstract` has any effect on a trait).

Is there any reason it needs to use a copy constructor rather than just implementing a clone method? It might be possible to get out of having to declare the [A] type on the class, but I've at least declared a self type so the compiler will make sure that the type matches the class.

```
trait DeepCloneable[A] { self: A =>
    def deepClone: A
}

class Egg(size: Int) extends DeepCloneable[Egg] {
    def deepClone = new Egg(size)
}

object Main extends App {
    val e = new Egg(3)
    println(e)
    println(e.deepClone)
}
```

http://ideone.com/CS9HTW

Comment: Thanks! The self type was not necessary, it seems.

Comment: Not necessary, but stops you doing something like `class Egg extends DeepCloneable[Potato]`.

Comment: Awesome - that helped me a lot ! Had a similar problem with data being parsed from a file to a template class and "deep" copied afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

- a. When you define a *type parameter* like the `A` it gets *erased* after the compilation phase.

  This means that the compiler uses type parameters to check that you use the correct types, but the resulting bytecode retains no information of `A`.

  This also implies that you cannot use `A` as a real class in code but only as a "type reference", because at runtime this information is lost.
- b & c. *traits* cannot define constructor parameters or auxiliary constructors by definition, they're also abstract by definition.

  What you can do is define a trait body that gets called upon instantiation of the concrete implementation

One alternative solution is to define a `Cloneable` *typeclass*. For more on this you can find lots of blogs on the subject, but I have no suggestion for a specific one.

[scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-type-class) has a huge part built using this pattern, maybe you can find inspiration there: you can look at [Order](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-type-class/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Order.scala), [Equal](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-type-class/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Equal.scala) or [Show](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-type-class/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Show.scala) to get the gist of it.

Comment: Good, clear answer. Especially thanks for the clarification of 'a'. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

It would suggest a typeclass based approach. With this it is possible to also let existing classes be cloneable:

```
class Foo(var x: Int)

trait Copyable[A] {
  def copy(a: A): A
}

implicit object FooCloneable extends Copyable[Foo] {
  def copy(foo: Foo) = new Foo(foo.x)
}

implicit def any2Copyable[A: Copyable](a: A) = new {
  def copy = implicitly[Copyable[A]].copy(a)
}


scala> val x = new Foo(2)
x: Foo = Foo@8d86328

scala> val y = x.copy
y: Foo = Foo@245e7588

scala> x eq y
res2: Boolean = false
```